# Create a NuGet package for .NET8 MAUI with Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, maui, pipeline

I have created a `.NET8 MAUI Class Library` to use in MAUI projects. The repo is in `Azure DevOps` and I was trying to build and publish the package via NuGet.

For that, I wrote a YAML file

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use dotnet 8'
  inputs:
    version: '8.0.x'
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'dotnet workload install maui'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore packages
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'c800d0d7-e2af-4567-997f-de7cf7888e6c'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build project
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/PSC.Maui.Components.BottomSheet.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

When the pipeline runs, I get this error

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
dotnet workload install maui
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/42901c0d-f407-4f75-912b-f93132efa865.sh
Workload ID maui isn't supported on this platform.

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: CmdLine
```

[image]

Then, I tried to create the NuGet package locally, but it was not recognized by the NuGet website when I uploaded it.

How can I change the pipeline?

Comment: Not a MAUI guy, but if I am not mistaken MAUI doesn't work on Linux, just Windows, Android and MacOS.

Comment: As people have mentioned, MAUI is not supported on Linux. Suggest using another `vmImage` for the VM such as `windows-latest`

Comment: @Enrico, may i know if changing the VM-image to windows(mentioned by dragon) works for you?

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT yes, changing the VM fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

.Net MAUI does not support Linux, therefore you can neither build to it or from it.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms?view=net-maui-8.0)

Comment: Ok, I can change the `vm-image` in `windows`